# Explode feature not working on few of formats in Autodesk forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

i have uploaded one 3D model into different formats (obj, stl, dwg) in A360 after checking into viewable of "https://myhub.autodesk360.com and https://dm.autodesk.io" the explode feature not working.

But in Dwg format explode feature working after half slider.

Comment: could you please share a minimal code example that reproduces the error?

Comment: i didn't write any code, i have uploaded model on A360 and check the same on this link "https://dm.autodesk.io" but all tools works fine except "explode".

Answer (score 0):

The explode feature should only work for files with a hierarchical structure, like assemblies & parts, or host and elements, etc. Usually .obj are simple shapes and this is not available.

Comment: Thanks for reply, an another issue also i have, a simple obj model i have uploaded in zip on same location. Texture of that model seems good but at when i have uploaded heavy scene into it only color material are visible not texture.

Comment: if is a different question, can you close this ("accept as an answer") and open a new one? I'll need more information to understand the texture problem, so please clarify on it. thanks